# Is there a php version which support Magento 2 all versions

Tags: magento2, php

I am testing a **Custom Module on Magento 2.1.12 and Magento 2.2.3**, I am using **Lampp** with **php version 7.1.3**, which is supportive for **magento 2.2.3** but not for **magento 2.1.12**.

What is the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

[image: Table comparison]

## So you can use: **7.0.2**, **7.0.4**, **7.0.6-7.0.x**

you should use php 7.0.2.

i’m running 7.0.2 too.

can run both 2.1.x and 2.2.x

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend **NOT** to simply take the short answer, which appears to be **7.0.2, 7.0.4, 7.0.6–7.0.x.**

There are other factors that may play into the compatibility, and to simply ask, *"...which PHP version works for...?"*, would be an answer for some but not for others.

**You should refer to documentation Magento has provided through their [DevDocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/).**  In addition to listing compatible versions of PHP that Magento2 can handle, PHP configuration settings that are recommended or required are listed too.

[Magento 2.2.x Technology Stack Requirements](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html)

- [PHP 7.0 or 7.1 on CentOS](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/php-centos.html)
- [Required PHP Settings](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/php-settings.html)

[Magento 2.1.x Technology Stack Requirements](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html)

- [PHP 7.0 or 7.1 on CentOS](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/php-centos.html)
- [Required PHP Settings](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/php-settings.html)

[Magento 2.0.x Technology Stack Requirements](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/prereq-overview.html)

---

Please keep in mind that there are other solutions beyond trying to find a single version of PHP for them.  Multiple versions of PHP can be used on the same server but differ across vhosts, for example.  Try reading something like this: https://medium.com/@sbuckpesch/run-multiple-php-version-on-the-same-server-using-php-fpm-and-xdebug-on-ubuntu-16-04-6a84f5b7d7ce